# Ruby - Multiplication issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, multiplication, floating-point-precision

My output is like this -

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > 2.32 * 3
=> 6.959999999999999
```

And I remember sometime back on another machine I had got it like.. `2.32 * 3 = 6`

What is my mistake?
Thanks a ton for reading this. :)

Comment: The previous one must have been truncated to an integer.

Comment: You're welcome. `2.32.to_i * 3 => 6`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to round down to an integer then just

```
(3 * 2.32).to_i
```

but I think that's unlikely. Usually you just want to format the slightly imprecise floating point number to something like this

```
"%0.2f" % (3 * 2.32) 
=> "6.96"
```

If you really want to work with the exact representation then you can use [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).

```
require 'BigDecimal'
(3 * BigDecimal.new("2.32")).to_s("F")
=> "6.96"
```

PS. Recommended read http://floating-point-gui.de/ DS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will print the real thing. But my real problem is different though... I want to round a float to precision up to two digits and store it in database. But it round() is not working for 2.33333333.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? `2.333333333333.round(2)` `=> 2.33`

Comment: I got it fixed. After rounding I was subtracting 0.01 which was again giving me the float inaccurate number to 2.3200000000000004. So now I am rounding it again after subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot tell you about Ruby, so please forgive me. But frankly the principles stay the same, so I hope that'll help:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2.32 * 3
6.959999999999999
```

As you can see, Python does the same.

```
System.out.println(2.32 * 3);
6.959999999999999
```

Java does the same! So what's wrong with it?

Let's try to move to `BigDecimal`s:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.32));
2.319999999999999840127884453977458178997039794921875
```

What you see here is what *actually* is meant by `2.32`. It's just that in most cases `print`, or `toString()`, or whatever your language uses for converting floats to strings, rounds the numbers a bit.

The inexact value, due to the fact that floats are in fact binary-represented reals, not decimal ones—which, in turn, makes those binaries *repeating,* or recurring. And as you can guess, repeating real in a limited space won't ever be exact.

Actually, I was lying when I said the scary decimal above is what is meant by `2.32`— the proper wording would be, "it's the closest decimal Java could get to approximate the actual value of `2.32`".

Read more here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: oh! I am getting it. I Keep forgetting the basics! I understand what you said that when the numbers are converted to string the problem is seen. But I think I can see the same value in the database too. Let me verify. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is just that `Float`s are not precise:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

That's not really language specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just covert `Float` to `BigDecimal` with `.to_d` to solve your Accuracy Problem

```
(2.32.to_d * 3.to_d).to_f
=> 6.96
```